# Redirect to every link present in particular column of a HTML table one by one in C#

Tags: c#, coded-ui-tests

I had retrieve one table from webpage in data table,or simply  say that i have one table in which first column contains different names and all this names are  hyperlink.Now my requirement is that i need to click each name one by one  in C# or coded ui. How i can do this?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please make an attempt at the problem first, post the code you have tried, and what did not work.  Once you have done that we can better assist you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it would look something like this:

```
[TestMethod]
public async Task TestAllTheLinks()
{
    BrowserWindow browserWindow = BrowserWindow.Launch("mywebsiteurl");

    HtmlTable table = new HtmlTable(browserWindow);
    table.SearchProperties.Add(HtmlTable.PropertyNames.Id, "tableId"); // or other search properties

    List<Exception> failureLinks = new List<Exception>();
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        for(int rowIndex = 0, max = table.RowCount; rowIndex < max; rowIndex++)
        {
            HtmlCell tableCell = table.GetCell(rowIndex, 0);
            HtmlHyperlink link = new HtmlHyperlink(tableCell);

            // are you sure you want to click?
            // how are you going to test rest of links if you nav away?
            Mouse.Click(link);

            // or would you rather just send an http request to that url to see if it is successful
            string href = link.Href;

            var result = await client.GetAsync(href);
            if (!result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
               failureLinks.Add(new Exception($"Link failed: {href}"));
            }
        }
    }

    if(failureLinks.Any()){
      throw new AggregateException(failureLinks);
    }
}
```